# What is an orl?

Tags: red-darkling

Red Darkling page 1:

> A croaking sound floated through the air. Red froze for a second,then relaxed and rolled her eyes. Was that supposed to be an orl? Idiot. She’d told Buck a hundred times to pick up a different signal. He couldn’t do an orl cry to save his life, and besides, orls didn’t even live on this planet.

What does she means by “orl”? Orls don’t live on this planet?

Comment: Seems to be some sort of animal?

Comment: Apart from the "orl", what about the "clomis" and the "yozzies"? I don't think it really matters what the details are, these words just set the atmosphere

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - Sure, but what is it?

Answer (score 3):

I asked my good friend Lea Anne Guettler this question and she was [kind enough to respond](https://twitter.com/la_guettler/status/1501590327253245957). In short, it's some sort of bird.

> **Q.** **What's an orl? What is it 'supposed' to sound like?**
>
> **LAG:** *What do you think it is, and what do you think it would sound like?*
>
> **Q.** **In the book Red says that Buck's "croaking sound" doesn't sound like one. I was guessing it was some kind of bird and that it
> makes a sound like a crow, but that's pure guesswork on my part.**
>
> **LAG:** *That's pretty much what I had in mind!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/la_guettler/status/1501590327253245957)</sup></sub>

Comment: I thought it would be some kind of space owl "primordial hoot".